# Custom Dynamic Array

Tags: c#, algorithm, array

Pretty simple class but just want to make sure I've approached it correctly.

```
public class DynamicArray<T> : IEnumerable<T>, ICollection<T>
    {
        private T[] _items;
        private int _size;
        private const int _growFactor = 2;

        public DynamicArray()
        {
            _items = new T[4];
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return _size;
            }
        }

        public bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void Add(T item)
        {
            if (_size + 1 > _items.Length)
            {
                var newArray = new T[_items.Length * _growFactor];
                _items.CopyTo(newArray, 0);
                _items = newArray;
            }
            _items[_size] = item;
            _size++;
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            _items = new T[2];
            _size = 0;
        }

        public bool Contains(T item)
        {
            foreach(var value in _items)
            {
                if (value.Equals(item))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            _items.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < _size; i++)
            {
                yield return _items[i];
            }
        }

        public bool Remove(T item)
        {
            for(var i = 0; i < _items.Length; i++)
            {
                if (_items[i].Equals(item))
                {
                    _items[i] = default(T);
                    _size--;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of minor points:

- In your constructor, you create an the array with an initial size of 4:

  ```
  _items = new T[4];
  ```

  However in your `Clear` method you set it to an size of 2:

  ```
  _items = new T[2];
  ```

  It's odd that you set it to a smaller number.  If you had a constant for initial size, or called `Clear` from the constructor this could be avoided.
- That said, do you *really* want clear to discard `_items`?  If you're reusing the array in a similar section of code, it seems reasonable to assume that after `Clear` has been called, there is a good chance the the array would grow again to a similar size.  It may be more efficient to simply reset `_size`, but leave `_items` intact.  Obviously this depends how you're using the array as to whether or not it's a good idea...
- You don't limit the size of the array.  Dynamic doubling whilst efficient, can get big pretty quick.  You *might* want to consider adding a maximum size to your array, again, this would depend on what you're using it for as to whether or not it's worth while.  List limits it's [growth](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,eb66b6616c6fd4ef) for example, albeit to a rather [large number](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,2d2b551eabe74985,references).

Answer (score -2):

I re-factored your implementation to be more efficient. 
Such as removing unnecessary **'for-loops'** and **extra variables**.

```
public class DynamicArray<T> : IEnumerable<T>, ICollection<T>
{
    private T[] _items;

    public DynamicArray()
    {
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            if (_items == null)
                return 0;
            return _items.Length;
        }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly => false;

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (_items == null)
        {
            _items = new T[1];
        }
        else
        {
            Array.Resize(ref _items,_items.Length+1);
        }
        _items[_items.Length - 1] = item;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _items = null;
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        if (_items == null)
            return false;
        return _items.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _items.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (_items == null)
            return Enumerable.Empty<T>().GetEnumerator();
        return _items.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
   }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return false;

        if(_items==null)
            return false;

        var temp = _items.Where(i => !i.Equals(item));
        _items = temp.ToArray();

        return true;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Please find below the Unit-Test class that I used to validate the implementation against your original intent.

```
[TestClass]
public class DynamicArrayTests
{

    private DynamicArray<int> _sut;


    [TestInitialize]
    public void Init()
    {
        _sut = new DynamicArray<int>();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ReadOnly_ShouldReturn_False()
    {
        Assert.IsFalse(_sut.IsReadOnly);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Count_ShouldReturn_InitialCount_0()
    {
        var expectedCount = 0;
        var actualCount = _sut.Count;
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedCount, actualCount);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Add_ShouldIncreaseCount()
    {
        var expectedCount = 1;

        _sut.Add(4);
        var actualCount = _sut.Count;

        Assert.AreEqual(expectedCount, actualCount);

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Clear_ShouldClearAllElements()
    {
        var expectedCount = 0;

        _sut.Clear();
        var actualCount = _sut.Count;

        Assert.AreEqual(expectedCount, actualCount);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Contains_ElementExists_True()
    {
        _sut.Add(5);
        var actual = _sut.Contains(5);

        Assert.IsTrue(actual);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetEnumerator_FromEmptyList_ReturnList()
    {
        var list = _sut.GetEnumerator();

        Assert.IsNotNull(list);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetEnumerator_ReturnExpectedValue()
    {
        _sut.Add(25);

        var list = _sut.GetEnumerator();
        list.MoveNext();

        Assert.IsTrue(list.Current.Equals(25));

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Remove_ShouldRemoveGivenElement_Return()
    {
        var expectedCount = 1; 

        _sut.Add(20);
        _sut.Add(30);

        var status = _sut.Remove(20);

        var actualCount = _sut.Count;

        var contains = _sut.Contains(20);

        Assert.IsTrue(status);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedCount, actualCount);
        Assert.IsFalse(contains);

    }

}
```

Also note that this implementation is not thread-safe.

Comment: So, this re-sizes every add, which essentially allocates a new array every time you add a new element. Isn't this somewhat inefficient compared to growing at an exponential rate?

Comment: @Scott, 
good catch. Answer is Yes and No :)
"Performance. Copying your array completely when resizing it is wasteful in many situations. For these cases, use List. But sometimes Array.Resize can lead to better performance. Arrays boost memory efficiency and lookup speed."
ref: (http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-resize)
I always prefer using BCL implementations rather using my own solutions.
Further, with this implementation, yo don't have to use additional variables to maintain state of your class.
Hope above link would give you more insight into Array.Resize(...)

Comment: This isn't a review. This is just your implementation which has numerous issues. For example, you let me put `null` into the list but then I can't remove it.

Comment: Hi @RobH, I tried to show him an implementation rather than reviewing by words. sometimes examples make sense. Thanks for pointing the null acceptance in the add(...) method. Would be appreciated you could point me the other '*numerous*' issues you observed in the code.

Comment: If you ask a question with this code in it I'll happily post a full review a bit later on.

Comment: @RobH, here we go (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/126101/do-you-see-any-issues-apprreciate-your-valuable-comments)

Appreciate your valuable comments. Please note that I update the Add(...) method to throw an exception upon receiving null as an input.

Comment: Following up with these comments and the other post has been really helpful. I do still think I like the growth factor approach as opposed to Array.Resize(), I just think that is a bit too inefficient.