# Implementing an array backed list

Tags: c#, comparative-review

I post the below code as review/answer to a question in codereview. 
([Custom Dynamic Array](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/125935/custom-dynamic-array))
however, seems the answer itself having issues looking at the comments that I received.
I would appreciate your valuable review comments:

```
public class DynamicArray<T> : IEnumerable<T>, ICollection<T>
{    
private T[] _items;

public DynamicArray()
{
}

public int Count
{
    get
    {
        if (_items == null)
            return 0;
        return _items.Length;
    }
}

public bool IsReadOnly => false;

public void Add(T item)
{
    if(item==null)
         throw new ArgumentException("item");

    if (_items == null)
    {
        _items = new T[1];
    }
    else
    {
        Array.Resize(ref _items,_items.Length+1);
    }
    _items[_items.Length - 1] = item;
}

public void Clear()
{
    _items = null;
}

public bool Contains(T item)
{
    if (_items == null)
        return false;
    return _items.Contains(item);
}

public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
{
    _items.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
}

public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    if (_items == null)
        return Enumerable.Empty<T>().GetEnumerator();
    return _items.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
   }

public bool Remove(T item)
{
    if (item == null)
        return false;

    if(_items==null)
        return false;

    var temp = _items.Where(i => !i.Equals(item));
    _items = temp.ToArray();

    return true;
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return GetEnumerator();
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have inconsistent spacing around your operators:

```
if(item==null)
```

vs

```
if (_items == null)
```

I generally prefer to see the second version (as I think is fairly standard in C#).

---

As you're using Expression Bodied Members. I know you're using C#6. Did you know about the `nameof` operator?

```
throw new ArgumentException("item");
```

Becomes

```
throw new ArgumentException(nameof(item));
```

That gives you compile time checking on the name of your parameter.

---

You should throw the most specific exception type available. If the argument is null and that isn't allowed. `throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item))`.

---

A <strike>list</strike> `DynamicArray` that doesn't allow `null` values is really odd. There is no reason why you should disallow `null`. You wouldn't stop me adding `0` to a list of integers.

---

You resize the array on every `Add`. That's O(n) and unnecessary. You should be creating an array larger than your current limit and then making it bigger (by some factor) when you reach the limit.

Also, under the covers, an `Array.Resize` simply creates a new array and copies everything over.

---

You have a bunch of things like this:

```
public bool Contains(T item)
{
    if (_items == null)
        return false;
    return _items.Contains(item);
}
```

Which could be written more simply as:

```
return _items != null && _items.Contains(item);
```

You could also use the `?.` null propagation operator:

```
return _items?.Contains(item) == true;
```

But it's a bit ugly because you have to do something to go from `Nullable<bool>` to a `bool`. I achieved that with a simple `== true` to force an implicit conversion.

---

Your `Remove` is incorrect. It should only remove the first occurrence of the item. [See msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bye7h94w(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

All your class is doing is keeping an array as a field and replacing it every time you modify the collection. It's not a very efficient way of doing it. As I said, you should be keeping an array with spare capacity that you resize when you need.

---

That's everything off the top of my head. I'll come back later when I have more time.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments. 
With reg C# 6 fetures, Reshaper forced me to use, but *nameof* I explicitly ignored.
Compacting statements, as you mentioned given for  the Containt(...) method. Isn't this reduce the readability of your code? I read somewhere, expand your conditions where possible for others to understand. Appreciate your review comments !

Comment: @RSF - That's an interesting question - I'd say the `obj != null && obj.Something()` is a well recognised pattern and I certainly grok it faster than the expanded version. Your mileage may vary of course :)